# How to remove ReactJS warning related to using a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler when the handler is actually defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So have an input field:

```
<input
  id={itemId}
  onChange={handleChange}
  type="number"
  value={packed}
/>
```

And here is my onChange function:

```
  handleChange(e) {
    const { items, onUpdateQuantity } = this.props;
    const updateItem = items.filter((item) =>
      item.itemId === e.target.id,
    );

    const itemQuantity = toNumber(e.target.value);
    updateItem.total += itemQuantity;
    onUpdateQuantity(e.target.id, itemQuantity);
  }
```

So why is React still complaining about an onChange handler not being defined when it already is? I don't want to add a `defaultValue` prop, as that causes bugs in my app. Any ideas?

Comment: does the onChange work? usually you have to bind the context of this to the event handler. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html check out this. it had a good example of onChange

Comment: where is `packed` coming from?

Comment: @floor Yes the onChange works, as I have binded it in my constructor.

Comment: Will setting `defaultValue={undefined}` cause problems in your app?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy do you mind posting all the code then? Hard to tell what the problem is when code is left out.

Answer (score 1):

That is coming because your `value` is not changing anywhere. As you can see from [docs for controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), the value of the `input` is `this.state.value` and the `onChange` method changes the value inside the `input` by changing `this.state.value`.

As far as I can see, when you input a value inside the `input` (`<input/>`) element, the value of that element is not changing. It is always whatever the value of `packed` is. That is why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you bind you function in the constructor

```
class bla extends Component {
    constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
  }
```

or if using stage 0 to have you have your function in this way.

```
handleChange = () => {}
```

and if not

```
 handleChange () {
     return (e) => {};
    }
```

Also, if your using a class component you should call your **handleChange** with **this.handleChange** if your passing it to functional component then what you have should be fine

Comment: @floor Care to elaborate?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy sure, look at the answer history of changes.  Even now it hardly makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that method.

Don't forget to use this.handleChange in you JSX

Example:

```
    class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```